# Qt project linking faces undefined references

Tags: c++, qt, linker

This is the .pro file:

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/agritrade
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

HEADERS += main.hpp
HEADERS += core/util.hpp

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp
SOURCES += core/util.cpp

# Installation path
# target.path =

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtviewer/qtviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

This is a portion of my codes (util.cpp):

```
/**
 * Get screen dimensions
 */
QRect Core::util::get_screen_dims() {
  return (new QDesktopWidget)->screenGeometry();
}
```

There are errors during building process (compilation ok, linking fails):

```
In function `ZN4Core4util15get_screen_dimsEv':
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN14QDesktopWidgetC1Ev'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK14QDesktopWidget14screenGeometryEi'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

I downloaded the whole installer of Qt 5 from qt-project.org to install. How strange that it has undefined references during project linking process.

Comment: Did you tell the linker to link to the QT libraries?

Comment: Show the `.pro` file (assuming you are using *qmake*, if not then explain how you build the project).

Comment: i thought installing Qt from the full Qt installer should have that kind of linkage ready? i have to link it manually? oh dear

Comment: my steps: (1) file->new project->qt quick, (2) write some test codes, (3) ctrl+b, (4) ctrl-r. It fails at step 3

Comment: @hyde .pro file now shown in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing this from the `.pro` file:

```
QT += widgets
```

You created a Qt Quick project, which I think leaves that out by default. If you mix both Qt Quick and [widgets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtwidgets-index.html), you need to add it there yourself.

That will tell *qmake* to add the right paths to build to include that module too. Remember to run *qmake* (from *Build* menu or by right-clicking the project and selecting it from the context menu) after editing `.pro`.

For reference: [*qmake* manual](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-manual.html)

Comment: hyde, you're powerful, it's the thing :) tks

Comment: Well, there's the qmake manual, added link to answer. If you mean, how to do the actual editing: it is listed in the project navigator along with source files, so just double click and it will be opened in Qt Creator editor. I don't think it matters where `QT` is modified withing the file, but it's customarily placed close to the top, even as the first thing in the file.